# Ionic app shows not http provider error

Tags: angularjs, api, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to implement a http request in ionic framework 3.1 application. I have created a provider named `apidata` using `ionic g provider apidata command` after which i created the following function in it that calls the api and logs the data returned by it on console.

```
  getremotedata(){
console.log(this.http.get('https://reverie.oiamigotech.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/?consumer_key=ck_xyz&consumer_secret=cs_xyz'));
  }
```

and have also imported the http package in the header as `import { Http } from '@angular/http';`

after which I updated the app.module.ts file to import the provider as `import { ApidataProvider } from '../providers/apidata/apidata';` and also added the same to the provider list as `providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    ApidataProvider
  ]`

now when i try to call the same from the home page after importing the package and using the following function and constructor definition

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public ApidataService: ApidataProvider) {
  }
  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.ApidataService.getremotedata();
  }
```

It generated the following error `Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Http!`

referred to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vuc4dp0qHSc for instructions about integration.

I am new to ionic and am unable to find and debug the issue. Any suggestions are greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import HttpModule and add it in **app.module.ts** page under imports like this,

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ]
```

remove any other http imports in your app.module.ts page and that should work

Comment: this works fine but there seems some another issue that when I check the console log it shows the code for main.js rather than the api return values.

Comment: what are you trying to console in app.module page? HttpModule is only for importing on app.module.ts page. For returning values from api you have to import http like this=> import { Http } from '@angular/http' in your provider

Comment: I have done the same I just want to console the values received from the api and am integrating this in app module because the function body is defined there.